# Multiple-Slit Interference Clarification

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

Source: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-3/pages/3-3-multiple-slit-interference

[image]

$dsin(\theta) = m \lambda$             (1)

where

$d \mbox{= spacing between slits}$

$\theta \mbox{= angle between path and line from the slits to the screen}$

$\lambda \mbox{= wavelength of electromagnetic radiation}$

Why does (1) hold for multiple slits?

For 3 slits, why would we not use $2dsin(\theta) = m\lambda$?

I was unable to understand the reasoning the textbook gave me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be useful to consider.

The main idea is that adjacent rays need to have a path length difference that is some integer multiple of the wavelength in order to get constructive interference.  In other words, the waves will be exactly in phase at the screen where the interference is happening at that angle $\theta$.

If two adjacent rays (say 1 and 2 in the figure) have a path difference of $d\sin \theta$, then rays 2 and 3 will also have a path difference of $d\sin \theta$.  This means that rays 1 and 3 will have a path difference of $2 d \sin \theta$.

I hope this helps.